# Can't create symlinks in virtualbox shared folders

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, virtualbox

A few days ago I found I can no longer create symlinks from Ubuntu in any directories that are shared with the OS X host.

```
ln: creating symbolic link `foo': Read-only file system
```

I'm able to create symlinks in non-shared folders and on OS X directly. I've also tried running disk repair, but no errors were found.

Setup:

- OS X 10.6.6
- Ubuntu server 11.04
- Virtualbox 4.1.8

Answer (score 47):

Another workaround is to run the following command on your host:

```
VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME 1
```

Or on Windows

```
VBoxManage.exe setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARE_NAME 1
```

where VM_NAME is the name of your virtual machine (e.g Ubuntu) and SHARE_NAME the name of your shared directory (without the "sf_" prefix).

This will re-enable the previous symlink friendly behavior.

Note: On Windows, **always** restart the Virtual Machine **AND** VirtualBox GUI.

Comment: How do you run that on a Windows host?

Comment: @Chris, VBoxManage is located in the Program Files directory (e.g. C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe).
That said, I have not been able to get the solution to work for me yet when hosting on windows (details at https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085#comment:16).

Comment: @schisamo can you confirm this actually worked for you on Windows/NTFS? I (and others) still get "read only file-system" as I describe in the ticket at https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085#comment:16.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work with a Windows host

Comment: This solution helped. The only thing you mustn't forget is to change SHARE_NAME to your actual share name

Comment: Restarting VBox GUI is also important

Comment: This  worked for me (Host: Kubuntu 14.04 x64, Guest: Kubuntu 14.04 x86) though I had to switch to the "VirtualBox VMs" folder on my machine to avoid a "Could not find a registered machine named ..." error.

Comment: Tried this on Windows, afterward got "protocol error" when creating links. Running VirtualBox as admin seems to have resolved it.

Comment: Could you please explain in details: SHARE_NAME the name of your shared directory (without the "sf_" prefix)

Comment: worked as a ubuntu host after restarting the virtual machine

Comment: Found on VirtualBox 6.1.4 too. Resolved with `Run as administrator` and the procedure explained in this answer for windows.

Comment: ANy exmaples of SHARE_NAME? for windows host is it name of the folder in linux guest e.g. /home/myuser/shared_lin or windows host "d:\mystaff\shared_win"

Answer (score 14):

On a windows host - run the virtual machine instance as an Administrator.  I found this solved the problem.

-- I tried @schisamo's suggestion first - it may be necessary to do both.  Apologies I would have added this as a comment but I'm so rep-poor I can't even comment ;-)

Comment: running as administrator worked

Comment: The combined solution worked for me. `Host OS : Windows 10 64 bit , VirtualBox version: 6.0, Guest OS : Ubuntu Xenial` . So, I ran the command as given in the accepted answer from my Windows host : `"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" setextradata net1mc1 VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/shared3 1`. `shared3` is the name of the shared folder given while creating the share. Then, I restarted VirtualBox as Admin user, and restarted the VM too. After this, I was able to create symbolic links from the guest OS's shared directory.

Answer (score 8):

This appears to be a bug in VirtualBox 4.1.8. Some people report that downgrading to 4.1.6 resolves the issue. See https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085