# VirtualBox VBoxManage: How can I see the current configuration?

Tags: configuration, virtual-machines, network-share, virtualbox, vboxmanage

VBoxManage provides some additional configuration possibilities for VirtualBox, for instance activating of symlinks in shared folders ([is still not working for me...](https://serverfault.com/questions/476610/virtualbox-issue-with-symlinks-in-shared-folders)):

```
C:\Windows\system32>VBoxManage setextradata "VM_NAME" VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARED_FOLDER_NAME 1
```

How can I see the current configuration? E.g. if `SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate` is set to 1 or not.

Thx

EDIT:

"VBoxManage provides some additional configuration possibilities for VirtualBox" -- that's wrong.

[VirtualBox Manual -> Chapter 8. VBoxManage -> Introduction](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp9764016): "VBoxManage is the command-line interface to VirtualBox."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `VBoxManage getextradata <VM> enumerate` what you're after? --official docs for ‘getextradata/setextradata’ at https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idm5419